# How do I select all the lifters who have never done running and swimming?

Tags: sql

How do I select all the lifters who have never done running and swimming?

activity_log

| user | week no. | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | swimming |
| a | 2 | lifting |
| b | 2 | lifting |
| a | 2 | lifting |
| d | 2 | lifting |
| c | 2 | running |
| b | 3 | climbing |
| c | 3 | running |
| a | 3 | lifting |

```
SELECT a.user 
FROM activity_log a
WHERE a.activity = 'lifting' AND a.user NOT IN (
 SELECT DISTINCT b.user 
 FROM activity_log b 
 WHERE b.activity IN ('running', 'swimming'))
```

so far here is my take but is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use the `HAVING` clause to avoid runners and swimmers.

```
SELECT a.user 
FROM activity_log a
GROUP BY a.user
HAVING SUM(when A.activity IN ('running', 'swimming') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Alternatively, use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT a.user FROM activity_log a
EXCEPT
SELECT a.user FROM activity_log a WHERE A.activity IN ('running', 'swimming')
```

(The GROUP BY query will probably perform better.)

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is a bit faster way to do it.

You can use JOIN instead of WHERE as `JOINS` are `faster` than `WHERE`. Here is how you query may look:

```
SELECT a.user 
FROM activity_log a
LEFT JOIN 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT b.user 
 FROM activity_log b 
 WHERE b.activity IN ('running', 'swimming')
) as c
ON a.user=c.user
WHERE a.activity = 'lifting' AND c.user IS NULL
```

As you might know, while using LEFT JOIN, we get NULL for `user` if they don't have activity as `running` or `swimming`. Hence taking `IS NULL` to filter.